# по какой причине первый вариант кода работает, а второй нет?

Tags: python

условие таково: На вход программе подается строка текста, содержащая различные натуральные числа. Из данной строки формируется список чисел. Напишите программу, которая меняет местами минимальный и максимальный элемент этого списка.

первый вариант рабочий

```
n = input().split()
for i in range(len(n)):
    n[i] = int(n[i])
maxi = n.index(max(n))
mini = n.index(min(n))
n[maxi],n[mini] = n[mini],n[maxi]
 
print(*n)
```

второй нет

```
n = input().split()
for i in range(len(n)):
    n[i] = int(n[i])
n[n.index(max(n))],n[n.index(min(n))] = n[n.index(min(n))],n[n.index(max(n))]
 
print(*n)
```

Comment: И почему он не рабочий?

Comment: Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь. (я запустил 5 12 23 8 и получил 23 12 5 8 - все работает).

Comment: @Сергей а теперь попробуйте `8 23 12 5`

Comment: спасибо, за помощь и замечания. это мой первый вопрос(поздравьте меня). Разобрался :)